# Struts2 : One jsp pages interacting with many Action classes

Tags: jsp, struts2, action

I'm a beginner in Struts2. I wonder if it would be a problem ( in running or Conception ) if the same page gets in interaction with many Action classes.

For example, **page.jsp with LoginAction.java, AdvertiseAction and NewsAction.java**. Thank you a lot for your advices!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by interaction? Do you want to return from different action classes to the same jsp or invoking different actions froom the same jsp. It should not be a problem and also I dont think its a bad idea.Most of the applications do the latter atleast.

Comment: I want to return from different Action classes to the same jsp. Okay, Thank you a lot, it's what I needed to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 is action-based. Of course a single jsp can interact with many action classes. All you need to do is to forward to your jsp after your action executes. This is usually done in `struts.xml`. But, why would you want to use a single jsp in your application?